# How to make a dynamic height UILabel push other elements out of its way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, autolayout

So I have a UILabel which is getting a dynamic amount of content from a database.
The more content it gets the more height the label gets accordingly.

For this effect I have used this code:

```
NSString *infoztext = [dataBase valueForKey:@"infos"];
    infoz.text = infoztext;
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320, 410);
    CGRect labrect = [infoztext boundingRectWithSize:maxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:infoz.font} context:Nil];
    infoz.numberOfLines = 0;
    infoz.frame = CGRectMake(23, 594, 274, labrect.size.height);
```

This works like a charm. The label will adjust its height to the amount of content it receives.

**THE PROBLEM** is that my label is overlapping all the elements in the view that are below it instead, of pushing them away.

**I do have autolayout enabled** but still nothing happens but overlapping.

How can I get the label to push other elements instead of overlap them?

Comment: For autolayout to work you need to set constraints. Are you setting any constraints anywhere? (either in Interface Builder or code)

Comment: I'm usually using the Interface Builder. I have all of my elements like labels and UIImageViews inside of ONE view that's inside a ScrollView. There I have set constraints. Got to be the easiest way to make the ScrollView work with the auto layout.

While testing I've just selected all of my elements and set "add missing constraints" but this didn't help me either.

Comment: If I select the next element right under my dynamical label and set "add missing constraints", the result is that my dynamical label will only adjust it's own height until it reaches the element below it, meaning it won't overlap it, but it also won't push it. It will only adjust it's own height until it reaches the other element and than limit it's own content. Like the element ist blocking the label from adjusting it's own height any further.

Answer (score 2):

In the interface builder, you can select an element (in this case the element immediately below your UILabel) and set constraints on that label.  In interface builder near the bottom right hand corner of the screen, there are 4 icons, select the one with the square in the middle.  You can select the redish I shape between the square and the top text field.  After that's selected, click "Add Constraints" and your app should keep the spacing between those two elements constant even after resizing the UILabel.

Note: You'll also have to do this to all elements underneath the UILabel or you'll run into the same problem further down the screen.

**EDIT:** The four icons at the bottom are "Align," "Pin," "Resolve Auto Layout Issues," and "Resizing Behavior."  The Icon needed for constraints is the "Pin" icon.  Click on that and the redish I should be near the top of the small window that pops up.

Comment: Thank you. The four icons you are probably talking about say (from left to right) "Align", "Pin", "Resolve Auto Layout Issues" and "Resizing behavior". As far as I can tell neither has a square in the middle nor is reddish. They are all monochrome.

Comment: You're looking for the "Pin" Icon, Click on that and you should see the redish I shape near the top of the pup up window.

Comment: Thx Victor this has gotten me a lot further.

LET ME SUMMERIZE HOW THIS IS DONE:
1) Select an element like a label
2) Click on "pin"
3) In the new Popup there is a square with 4x textfields in all four directions of it. There are TINY reddish strokes. You have to actually CLICK ON THEM to "activate" the value in the associated textfield. If you click the drop down arrow beside the textfield you can also chose which other element exactly should be the measuring point. 

But let me tell you...I have like 20 elements under the dynamic label and it's a pain in the *ss to get them all to work :(